# safer library whether to use poi or spire.doc in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, spire.doc

I have a project to combine multiple docx documents into 1 docx file using spring boot. I'm confused about using the poi library or E-iceblue's free Spire.Doc. I've managed to use those two libraries. And I'm more comfortable using the spire library because its use is simpler. What I want to ask is is it safe to use E-iceblue's free Spire.Doc library in a large project? Does it have a license?

Here are the dependencies and repositories in pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>e-iceblue</groupId>
        <artifactId>spire.doc.free</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.e-iceblue</id>
        <name>e-iceblue</name>
        <url>http://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it have a license?

[This](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-for-java.html) says:

> Free version is limited to 500 paragraphs and 25 tables. This limitation is enforced during reading or writing files. When converting word documents to PDF and XPS files, you can only get the first 3 pages of PDF file. Upgrade to Commercial Edition of Spire.Doc for Java.

So it is pretty limited. It depends on your use case. If this is enough for you, go for it, else you'll have to do with Apache POI. Which is a great mature library.

Comment: I think so. Thank you Renis